# Is this a local diffeomorphism?

Tags: differential-topology

I want to find a local diffeomorphism $\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$ that is not a diffeomorphism onto its image. This is what I thought:
$f(x,y)=(\sin 2\pi x, \cos 2\pi y)$. Does that work? Seems ok to me.

Comment: What does the derivative look like that the point $(1/4, 0)$?

Comment: Yeah, the jacobian is not invertible so it is not a local diffeomorphism at this point. thanks

Comment: the exponential function does it quite nicely (on $\mathbb{C}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Complex_plane

Comment: possible duplicate of [surjective immersion $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ which is not a diffeomorphism](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553299/surjective-immersion-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr2-which-is-not-a-diffeomorphi)

Answer (score 1):

$\left(x,y\right)\mapsto\left(e^{x}sin\left(y\right),e^{x}cos\left(y\right)\right)$